# Help with distance question points A and B

Tags: contest-math

[image]

Ok. I had no idea how to do the question but I tried fiddling with the triangles to see if I can get any value but only managed to get $MN$. I read the solution to this question, and it said that I should make $M$ coincide with $N$ so that we get $AMB$ as a straight line. I understood that, but then it said that $AMB$ is the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle with sides length of **5** and 12. How is one of the sides 5? shouldn't it be 3 as in the photo?

Comment: Let the opposite banks of the river approach each other until they coincide. The $5$ is $3+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to eliminate the river from the picture. Euclid's axiom tells you that the shortest distance between any two points (here, $A,B$) lies along the straight line through them. Here, the line segment $AB$ would be the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle with sides $12$ and $2+3=5$.